# Understanding performance of an index fund

Tags: stocks, canada, mutual-funds, index-fund

I am trying to understand how to interpret the performance of an index fund.  I have two views of the same [TDB911](https://www.td.com/ca/en/asset-management/funds/solutions/mutual-funds/FundCard/TD%20International%20Index%20Fund%20-%20e/?fundId=4877) fund.

The view in TD WebBroker (investing interface) shows that at the beginning of a 20 year period closed at `12.81`, and at the end it's `12.83`, indicating that the gain within the period is completely negligible at `+0.15%`.

Meanwhile, the gain from the fund facts page indicates a change of `10,000` initial investment would yield `17,160`, or a gain of `+71.61%`, which is a much more realistic number.

How would I interpret the TD WebBroker UI in comparison to the TD Fund Facts page?

TD WebBroker UI
[image: TD WebBroker UI]

[TD Fund Page](https://www.td.com/ca/en/asset-management/funds/solutions/mutual-funds/FundCard/TD%20International%20Index%20Fund%20-%20e/?fundId=4877)
[image: TD Fund Page]

Comment: Perhaps because the share price of an index fund does not include the distributions (dividends and capital gains) paid out by the fund each year, only the change in value of the price of the shares of the various stock holdings of the fund?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top chart is the share price of the fund.  The bottom chart reflects what would happen if you reinvested dividends.  In this case, the overwhelming majority of the fund's gains have been distributed as dividends.

From the fund's page, there is a link to [TD's graphing tool](https://www.td.com/ca/en/asset-management/resources/graphing-tool/) where you can experiment with, among other things, whether dividends were reinvested or not.  If you choose "No" there, you'll get a chart that matches the share price change

[image: Performance without dividends reinvested]